# Why can't I download the same books to Adobe Digital Editions and Overdrive apps?

Tags: epub, library, adobe-digital-editions, apps

According to Overdrive, if I get an ebook from a participating library, I should be able to get it on up to six devices, as long as I login with the Overdrive ID on each.

So I've checked out a book, and managed to get it without a problem, onto:

1. Overdrive app on my iPad,
2. Overdrive app on my Windows 8 PC (the one in the app store).

Then I'm trying to get it onto Adobe Digital Editions on my Mac, and ADE, when reading the .ascm file, says it's linked to another user.

Just to note, I've authorized ADE with my Overdrive login, and I've never used AdobeID directly.

I can also get another book from the same library, download it into ADE just fine, but then the apps (both iOS and Windows 8) refuse to download it, saying it's authorized to a different user.

So apparently, Overdrive apps and ADE with Overdrive login generate different Adobe IDs (although looking in the settings shows the same thing).

What is going on, and how do I solve the issue--i.e. get the same book on Overdrive apps and ADE?

Answer (score 1):

[Use your Overdrive account to authorize ADE](http://help.overdrive.com/customer/portal/articles/1481077-how-to-authorize-adobe-digital-editions-on-a-computer):

"If you plan to use ADE and our mobile app, we encourage you to use your [OverDrive account](http://help.overdrive.com/customer/portal/articles/1481535) to authorize ADE. That way, you won't run into authorization issues when you read the same eBooks on your mobile device and on your computer. You can sign up for an OverDrive account through our mobile app or on overdrive.com."

Comment: He said he did that... But I'd recommend de-authorizing ADE and trying again, because it certainly looks as if they're using different IDs

Comment: Yeah, I did. I also tried reauthorization, and even deleting and freshly reinstalling ADE, with no results.